# How to change Node-RED Gauge Color dynamically

Tags: javascript, dashboard, node-red

[here](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-dashboard/blob/master/config-fields.md) on GitHub I found out that it should be possible to change the color of the gage with the **colors** property dynamically.

However the following code is not working. The **min** and **max** properties works fine. Only the **colors** property doesn't seems to work.
Any Ideas why?

```
msg.ui_control = {
    "gtype": "gage",

    "options":{
        "min": 0,
        "max": 200,
        "colors": ["blue","blue", "blue"]    
    }
}
return msg;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

colors is not an option, it should be plced directly under gtype

Comment: you are right, now it works. thank you so much. I should've guessed

Comment: Please review your post for spelling, capitalisation, punctuation and formatting ( https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ).